# Is this the fastest way to get records in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, latency

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE
((samaccountname_s='".$sender."' AND samaccountname_r='".$contact."') OR
(samaccountname_s='".$contact."' AND samaccountname_r='".$sender."'))
ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

And it is seriously slow, I think some of the latency may be down to the server, but I can't help but think there is a more efficient query to get the result that I'm looking for above.

In short: The query checks to see if there are messages between two people (`$sender` and `$contact`)

Could this be done any more efficiently/quickly?

Comment: How big is the table?  Do you have any indexes on it?

Comment: do you have indexes on table ? use `EXPLAIN` how mysql optimizer treating

Comment: please show your `CREATE TABLE` statement.  You likely need some (or better) indices.

Comment: May be a better question for [dba.se](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Alnitak I know about prepared statements, and for this situation, they're not necessary. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: You need to show us the table and index definitions.  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put indices on `samaccountname_s` and `samaccountname_r`.  Since you're checking both in one query, put them in the same index.  Like this

```
ALTER TABLE mytable add INDEX sam_index (samaccountname_s, samaccountname_r);
```

or like this

```
CREATE INDEX sam_index ON mytable (samaccountname_s, samaccountname_r);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add some indexes to the table.  At the very least you'll want to index the `samaccountname_s` and `samaccountname_r` fields.  Like so:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD INDEX IDX_tablename_samaccountname_s (samaccountname_s);
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD INDEX IDX_tablename_samaccountname_r (samaccountname_r);
```

Indexing the timestamp column might help as well since you are using it in your order by:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD INDEX IDX_tablename_timestamp (timestamp);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what it means to 'index' columns, job for Google?

Comment: @F4r-20 - added the statements for it.  Run those once and see how it changes things for ya.

Comment: @F4r-20 - yup, only need to run them once to create the indexes.  You should never need to run them again after that (unless you drop and re-create the table)

Comment: @AndyLester I meant as oppose to having to do it more than once. Thanks Eric good help.

Comment: yes, that query modifies the table to add the index. A index means the database is storing additional information about those fields so they can be accessed and compared directly. for instance: you want to look for the row `WHERE id='1'` , if you don't have the field `id` indexed the query will retrieve ALL the rows, then compare them 1 by 1 until it find all the rows with `id='1'`. If you have an index it can directly access all of them with `id=1`, executing this query in less than a second.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing indices.

Basically, indices make lots of searching for data feasible from a performance standpoint. The only reason that columns are not always indexed, is because indices also slow down inserts, although not by much. A good general rule is to keep indices on fields that you normally search by, for example foreign keys and such.

Here is the MySQL article on how to create an index:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

The columns you should have indexed in your query are:

- samaccountname_s
- samaccountname_r
- timestamp

Hope it helps!

P.S.: You really should escape the values in that query. Consider switching to PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php), or at the very least, use manual escaping: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php